# factory_girl does not set model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

factory_girl is not setting the url attribute on the model correctly. I looked to see if there are reserved words, but I found nothing.

```
  factory :attachment do
    association :attachable, factory: :upload

    url "some/path"
    description "Some important file"
  end
```

I get this failure. Notice `url: nil`

```
1) Attachment should be valid
     Failure/Error: it { should be_valid }
       expected #<Attachment id: 1048, attachable_id: 1047, attachable_type: "Upload", name: nil, url: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, description: "Some important file"> to be valid, but got errors: Url can't be empty
     # ./spec/models/attachment_spec.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I ran factory_girl in the console and got the same result with `FactorGirl.attributes_for :attachment`

Running Rails 4 with FactoryGirl 4.2.1.

Comment: Does it get set when you do `FactoryGirl.build(:attachment, :url => "some/path")`?

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same issue and after hours of banging my head on the desk I decided to stop and restart my Spring server. It started working like magic.

Before restarting my Spring server I was able to set attributes using `create :object, new_field: true` but just using `create :object` wouldn't work, even if I had `new_field true` in my `factories.rb` file.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but I had the same problem. I had added all my attributes after the initial migration, and it turned out I was using `attr_accessor` instead of `attr_accessible` in my model.